# Extra colon ':' added at end of JSON, in header form data (it is a XHR)

Tags: json, jmeter, xmlhttprequest

Using JMeter to record scripts.
Port : 8080
Chrome : Proxy Server settings done on port 8080

i am getting this error in Developer tool
500 (Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: =. Path '', line 1, position 4083.)

When i checked Header Form Data it showed me a extra colon ':' at the end of the JSON, and due to which i got this error 
500 (Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: =. Path '', line 1, position 4083.)

When i removed all proxy settings from Chrome adn tried it worked without any error.
But this wont help me as i cant record scripts in JMeter without proxy server setting :(

Could anyone please help me know why Extra colon is added at end of JSON in Header Form data.

Comment: are you sure it was at the end of JSON? Rather sounds like some sort of buffer was overflown, and you are getting incomplete JSON?

Comment: JSON is complete.
Just one extra colon is appended at the end.
Is JMeter adding this extra colon ? if yes then how to get rid of it

Comment: I would suggest to try with different browser like firefox or Ie. and to validate the colon is only shown in chrome, use burp suite or any other network sniffer tool or Network tab in browser developer options (F12 -> Network in all browsers) to capture response and see whether you observe the colon there as well.

Comment: Hello. I'd just like to say that I have the exact same issue for this. I'm building a POST request in a Google Chrome extension by running JSON.stringify on a javascript object, and I too have an extra colon `:` at the end of my request body. Did you ever find a solution for your JMeter tests?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome appends the additional colon at end of the json each time. This is why, while recording through JMeter 'HTTP(S) Test yrScript Recorder' the POST request fails.
Solution:
- Try to update the Request in JMeter by removing the colon
- Record the script using Blazemeter Recorder